# Recursion with Doctrine ORM - logical error

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

Hallo,

I have sort of daily random image system build with Codeigniter and Doctrine.

There is key function, which returns daily image or sets new one. I am using recursive calling, but *sometimes are two images selected for one day*.

```
class Daily extends Controller {

    function find_daily(){
        $connection = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
        $connection->setCharset('utf8');

        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('COUNT(id) as dailycount')
            ->from('Image')
            ->where('daily_date = ?',date("Y-m-d"));



        $set = $q->execute();

        if( $set[0]->dailycount != 0 ){ //theres one or more for today



            $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('id')
            ->from('Image')
            ->where('daily_date = ?',date("Y-m-d"))
            ->limit(1);


            $set = $q->execute();
            $i = Doctrine::getTable('Image')->findOneById($set[0]["id"]);

            return $i;

            }else { // none image selected with today date


                $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->select('id')
                ->from('Image')
                ->where('daily_date = ?', "0000-00-00")
                ->andWhere("dir =?","queue")
                ->orderBy("rand()")
                ->limit(1);


                $set = $q->execute();


                $i = Doctrine::getTable('Image')->findOneById($set[0]["id"]);

                $i->daily_date = date("Y-m-d");
                $i->dir = "archive";
                $i->save();

                $this -> find_daily();
                };

        }

...
```

I think theres some stupid mistake.. maybe calling something like "Doctrine::doAllAndClear" before `$this -> find_daily();` or I forget something...

Or is better not to use recursive calls?

Thanks.

Comment: Bear with me, because I may just be getting confused by your code, but why are you recursing? Why not, say, just `return $i;` instead of calling `$this->find_daily()` again? Also, with your current if you recurse, whatever's calling you won't receive a return value, will it? Because you're not returning the result of the recursive call. We may need to see the rest of the function to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Also, how is this code being kicked off? Is there a chance that two users are running this simultaneously?

Comment: @matt You are right I can do it without recursion... and I propably do it that way, but I will be glad to find what I am doing wrong. This code is used when some user views daily image. I have curently about 10 users (project is not public). My table is timestampable - and both images are selected (db rows updated) in same time. I think is not posible to have two users at same time (in midnight) on same script now (and this issue shows repeatedly).

Comment: What _is_ the timestamp when they're the same? Do you mention midnight because the timestamps are around midnight? If this script runs at midnight, it's possible that the value of `date("Y-m-d")` will change while it's running, of course...

Comment: Doctrine place automaticly actual date and time on every row on each update - this I mean by timestamp. I think change of date during script execution is not problem, in worst case system return old image. This "double selection" issue shows circa each second day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've not tested this at all, but I'd probably be more likely to write your code more like this; hopefully this will give you some ideas:

```
  function find_daily() {
    $connection = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
    $connection->setCharset('utf8');

    // Make sure "today" doesn't change while the script runs
    $today = date("Y-m-d"); 

    // Find an image with today's date.
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
      ->from('Image')
      ->where('daily_date = ?', $today)
      ->limit(1);

    $image = $q->fetchOne();

    if (!$image) {
      // There was no image with today's date, so pick one from the queue at random instead.
      $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Image')
        ->where('daily_date = ?', "0000-00-00")
        ->andWhere("dir =?","queue")
        ->orderBy("rand()")
        ->limit(1);

      $image = $q->fetchOne();
      // ToDo: Cope with there being no image in the queue

      $image->setDailyDate($today);
      $image->setDir("archive");
      $image->save();
    }
    return $image;
  }
```

However, you need to think about what happens if two people hit your script at the same time. In that case, they may *both* fetch a new image for the day (because they could each run the first `SELECT` at the same time, and both get a result that says there's no daily image yet.)

To avoid that, I'd guess you'd want to wrap this in a transaction, and set a transaction isolation level such that the first caller of the function "wins" the race condition, and subsequent callers block until the update is safely saved. Not entirely sure how you'd do that with Doctrine, but it shouldn't be hard.

Checking the manual, a `beginTransaction()` at the start, a `commit()` at the end, and a setup before everything else involving `$tx = $conn->transaction; $tx->setIsolation('SERIALIZABLE');` (otherwise two users could probably still run the SELECT at once) would probably be all you need, but you might want to wait for someone who really knows Doctrine to comment on that...

I also saved "today"'s date at the start of the script, otherwise there's a danger of it being different during the SELECT and the later UPDATE, if the script runs across midnight.

Comment: Thanks, transactions are completely new for me. I change my code, to avoid that stupid recursion.

Comment: @Jan Thinking about it, I'm not entirely convinced transactions will do the job here; you're basing a update on the previous result of looking at the whole table (to find whether there are any rows with today's date.) Locking the table while this function runs would do the job, but you might want to wait and see if anyone's got any better ideas before you accept an answer here.

Comment: waiting thats exactly what I'm doing now :) its small project - so I can afford it. Thanks.

Comment: I finaly find source of that bug :) It was my stupidity and I solve it in Cafeteria. I forget that one another image (with description) generate itself using same function.